# How to extract icons/iconography from APKs

Tags: apk, fonts, app-icons, graphics

I just want to know if it's possible to break open an APK (say from Facebook, Twitter, Periscope, Instagram, YouTube) to get their unique iconography sets (for personal UX concept works and uses only, their copyrights is all on them). Whether it's a sprite, individual PNGs, SVG files, or even better font glyphs? Where could I find them? Most of the time they're on assets, but most of the other time they're not? Where could I find them and extract them?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try in drawable folder?

Comment: `res/` inside the APK. That's most of them. Maybe a few others in `assets/`. Anyway, why not extract them all and use your system's find function?

Comment: The .png images are usually in res/drawable folder after decompiling the apk.  The best tool to decompile is apktool